How to handle PaymentActionRequired exceptions when swapping plans using Stripe Checkout?
I'm using Cashier to handle subscription billing via Stripe Checkout.
When a subscriber wants to swap their plan (and I need them to be billed immediately), I use the swapAndInvoice method.
In many cases, this returns a PaymentActionRequired exception - e.g. the user needs to do 3D Secure authentication.
It's not clear to me in the documentation how to handle this if I am using Checkout. I could create an entirely new subscription checkout, but that would result in a second subscription, rather than updating the existing one. Can I redirect to Checkout in a way that means the user is updating a current subscription, rather than creating a new one?
Thanks for any help with this.

It depends on what swapAndInvoice does under the hood, but on a Stripe context, your Subscription has an Invoice, which has a PaymentIntent and now is in requires_action status. You want to confirm that PaymentIntent to move the Subscription to an active state, not creating any extra Subscription. You would generally need another integration than Checkout to confirm that PaymentIntent in requires_action mode.

Thanks for the reply. Looks like I need to use Cashier's included payment view to handle the confirmation locally.
